# Problema ao adicionar imagens C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image

Estou tentando criar um objeto do tipo **Image** a partir de uma imagem já existente, que será inserido em um **Frame** e que por sua vez será inserido em um **StackPanel**. No entanto, apenas imagens/ícones que estão inseridas dentro do projeto são exibidas no componente (#2). fiz testes para verificar se é o arquivo que não existe, porém não entra (#1).

Alguém sabe o que é? Todos os arquivos estão com permissão de acesso para todos os usuários...

```
if (!File.Exists("C:/Users/32-add.png")) MessageBox.Show("");
//teste para verificar a existência (#1)

//Uri imageUri = new Uri(photoPath + "32-star.png", UriKind.Relative);

//testando com um ícone do meu projeto, aqui vai (#2)

Uri imageUri = new Uri("C:/Users/32-add.png", UriKind.Relative);
//aqui não vai

BitmapImage imageBitmap = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
Image img = new Image {Source=imageBitmap, Width = 130, Height = 130, MinWidth = 130, MinHeight = 130};
//conversão

Frame frame = new Frame{Content = img};

stackPanel.Children.Add(frame);
```

Comment: Consegui resolver o meu problema com o vídeo, em inglês: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nb89r13Z1q4 Grato :)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar apenas uma `\`, mas para isso, coloque um `@` na frente da string:

```
File.Exists(@"C:\Users\32-add.png")
```

E também pode utilizar duas `\`, porém sem o `@`:

```
File.Exists("C:\\Users\\32-add.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema está em como você passa o caminho da imagem. Para caminhos absolutos, deve-se usar a barra invertida, ficando:

```
if (!File.Exists("C:\\Users\\32-add.png")) MessageBox.Show("");
```

Comment: Não deveria escapar a barra invertida? Para evitar que `\n` seja interpretado como quebra de linha?

Comment: Se eu deixo apenas um \ para definição do path, ele me retorna erros de representação de texto para UTF 16 (?), eu uso a barra invertida por ser como eu uso para a localização do path com os meus ícones adicionados ao projeto, e que são reconhecidos com sucesso... Não sei se isso tem algo a ver, mas, é WPF

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Isso mesmo. Corrigi a resposta baseada em sua observação.